# Would the Following be Correctly Formated?

Tags: grammar

> Cass’s body arched violently off of the bed, his mouth open and
>   shrieking, arms flailing outward to protect from unseen invaders. The
>   doctors, still dressed in pajamas, are stunned, jaws loose. An orderly
>   is the first to react, rushing to Michael and heaving the frightened
>   boy off of his bed and away from the spasming teen across the room.
>   Children are out of bed, crowding around the glass plates in their
>   doors to watch.
>
> Doctors kick into action, scuttling forward like a pack of robe-strewn
>   mice. A petite female rushes from the room in search of anesthesia and
>   larger men and women attempt to flatten the boy’s limbs to the
>   mattress, pressing his back down before Cassie can break something.
>   Break himself.   And then the floor *glows*. A dark violet-pink that
>   had everyone scurrying back away. The boy may be important, but not
>   more so than their own lives, after all, he’s practically unfixable.

So basically, should I be making sure all words like is/are, was/were and has/had are all the same?

Like: "And then the floor *glows*. A dark violet-pink that **had** everyone scurrying back away. The boy may **have been** important, but not more so than their own lives, after all, **he was** practically unfixable."

Comment: Asking for help with grammar is off-topic here, as are requests for general critique. For more information, see the [help center](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Yes, all the verbs should be the same tense. That means not just 'is'/'are' but 'arches', 'glows', 'kick', 'rushes' etc.

Present tense:

> Cass’s body arches violently off of the bed, his mouth open and shrieking, arms flailing outward to protect from unseen invaders. The doctors, still dressed in pajamas, are stunned, jaws loose. An orderly is the first to react, rushing to Michael and heaving the frightened boy off of his bed and away from the spasming teen across the room. Children are out of bed, crowding around the glass plates in their doors to watch.

Past Tense:

> Cass’s body arched violently off of the bed, his mouth open and shrieking, arms flailing outward to protect from unseen invaders. The doctors, still dressed in pajamas, were stunned, jaws loose. An orderly was the first to react, rushing to Michael and heaving the frightened boy off of his bed and away from the spasming teen across the room. Children were out of bed, crowding around the glass plates in their doors to watch.

It's common in some forms of colloquial speech to mix tenses when storytelling, especially to emphasise certain actions, but this is definitely wrong when writing.

For example:

> So he said 'blah,' and then I said, 'whatever,' then he punches me in the face!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I knew that it looked kind of odd, I just wasn't sure why, so thanks a lot!